# Plotting heatmap of weights in a neural network on a background image

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, seaborn

I have this problem to showcase the original image given to me to be visualized in a way that the original image is in the background and the weights assigned are in the seaborn heatmap form.

Example heatmap picture:
[image]

I found some answers on visualizing this using confusion matrix, but weights is a different thing all the way.

Also I want to ask that is it even possible to visualize the image in such a way, as if a image is 28x28, how do a 3x3 weight can cover it all up?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your heatmap is coming from the feature maps of a convolutional layer in your network and that you want to use a technique such as CAM (class activation maps) or grad-CAM (gradient-weighted class activation maps).

Suppose that you have converted your convolutional feature maps into a heatmap as a 14x14 numpy array and you want to overlay it on an image of 256x256 pixels. The heatmap contains float32 numbers between 0 and 1. The idea is to upsample the 14x14 feature map to 256x256 first, using opencv for instance:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('./my-image.png')
# Resize the heatmap
heatmap = cv2.resize(heatmap, (img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))
# Convert dtype to uint8
heatmap = np.uint8(255 * heatmap)
# Overlay the heatmap on the image
heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(heatmap, cv2.COLORMAP_RAINBOW)
result = cv2.addWeighted(img, 0.6, heatmap, 0.4, 0)
```

You can plot the result using matplotlib:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(result)
```

This is a pure matplotlib solution and not a seaborn solution. Seaborn mostly provides matplotlib wrappers, so you should be able to take it from here. For a complete grad-cam example (and the source code for this answer), you can [refer to this blogpost](http://www.hackevolve.com/where-cnn-is-looking-grad-cam/).